# Which is the correct GnuPG executable to use to configure Enigmail?

Tags: thunderbird, enigmail

I'm trying to setup Enigmail to work in Thunderbird.

Enigmail says it `could not find GnuPG` when I open Thunderbird > Tools > Addons > Extensions > Enigmail Preferences > Basic tab.

I looked in my `/usr/bin` and see there are several executables that seem relevant. Which is the correct one to specify?

- gpg
- gpg2
- gpg-agent

Answer (score 2):

Enigmail wants the "gpg" command-line tool.  (gpg-agent is a helper tool, and I don't know what "gpg2" is - that's not present on my system.)

So, you want to give it:

```
/usr/bin/gpg
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using gpg2 as it is geared towards the desktop.

Under OpenPGP -> Preferences, check "Override with" and put in the following in the link next to it:

```
/usr/bin/gpg2
```

If it gives you a further error message, install gnupg2

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg2
```

Note, **do NOT uninstall gnupg**. This is still used by many other parts of the operating system, including aptitude itself.

Answer (score 1):

On Quantal I have:

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.11
```

and:

```
gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.17

libgcrypt 1.5.0
```

The problem I'm having and the reason I wanted to see if Enigmail can make my key (how I ended up here) is that both *gpg --gen-key* and *gpg2 --gen-key* are giving me grief from CLI and the GPA Privacy Assistant won't allow me to generate a 4096 key. Turning out a bit complicated for a beginner. :)

I will not know what to add either, without just trying it (I guess), because besides what dholbert listed - there is also:

```
~$ whereis gpg
gpg: /usr/bin/gpg /usr/bin/X11/gpg /usr/share/man/man1/gpg.1.gz

~$ whereis gpg2
gpg2: /usr/bin/gpg2 /usr/bin/X11/gpg2 /usr/share/man/man1/gpg2.1.gz
```

No telling how it will turn out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto